# What is this hole used for in this nameplate for Shimano 105 5800 Brake Shifter?

Tags: road-bike, brakes, shifter

That hole circled in red, what is it for?

[image]

Comment: BUMP!! Does anyone know!? Dead forums!

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! I noticed your "Bump" comment. This works differently from a traditional online forum. You may want to take the [tour] for more information on how to get the most out of this and other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Sam Calm down—we all have lives outside of stack exchange, and nobody here is obligated to answer anything.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not positive, but I believe the other two holes are for the mounting screws.  That would mean that this third, non-beveled hole may be the access port for the grip adjustment screw. It would be much easier to tell if you had another picture of the lever partially assembled.

If it is an access for the grip adjustment, you should be able to peel the rubber cover back and then use that adjustment screw to change the "reach" between the lever and the bar to allow for ease of use and comfort for people with different size hands.

It's also possible that the grip adjustment is in another location and that the hole exists simply to reduce the weight of the part.

Comment: Or the part is from a similar model of bicycle, which shares this part. But rather than machine 2 different parts, 1 common part is used and finished differently for models A and B.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that it is some sort of artifact from the injection molding process. I’m not too familiar with what that may entail, but I presume it could be the result of an alignment pin, or perhaps something to ease removal/extraction. I doubt it’s a weight saving thing because there could be a lot more material removed here if weight reduction was the goal; why is there only that one hole then?

Answer (score 1):

On my old 105 shifters, there's a boss on the block which goes into a locating hole on the cover - completely different to this but might be the same general concept.

Two screws should do the same job without a locating peg, so this is more of a possibility than an answer.